# trigger event in js when opening email?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to track when a user opens an email for a subscription service I have. Is it possible to trigger some event in javascript or something else when an email is opened?

Answer (score 0):

most email clients' security models won't allow this.

The common way to do this is to embed an external image in your message, where the image is an active page that is able to log the fact that the email has been opened (normally you would also capture the email address and the user's IP). This relies on the user allowing the message to load external images.

I would like to add that please, only do this for the right reasons... don't be evil.